# Customising Colour / Boldness in Markdown with RMarkdown / Bookdown

Tags: css, r-markdown, markdown, bookdown

I am using **bookdown** to write some maths lecture notes. I find myself very often using the `> blockquote` feature. Often, this is because my environments, such as remarks and exercises take multiple lines. It is then ambiguous where the theorem ends and where 'chat' begins after.<sup>1</sup> I'm pretty happy with doing this. I like the fact that the blockquote singles out the environments so it's very easy to see when one is changing to another. The thing I don't like is that it "softens" the text colour.

See the following screenshot, comparing the boldness of the font in the first paragraph with that in the blockquote.

[image]

Is there any way of removing this "softening"?

<sup>1</sup>
LaTeX gets around this by adding extra white-space around something like `\begin{example} ... \end{example}`. Alternatively, one can configure them to add a `\qedsymbol` to indicate that they have come to an end. I don't feel the first option would look nice in **bookdown** and I don't think the second option is even possible. It would actually be great for my long examples if it did!

Comment: Are you concerned about the lighter text in the HTML or the PDF output, or both?

Comment: @jtbayly Both. I have only set up HTML output so far, so I don't actually know what it looks like in the PDF one. Sorry, I should've mentioned that!

Comment: You can always set styles for the HTML to change the appearance of anything in your document; `<style>blockquote {font-color: black; opacity: 1;}</style>` I don't know what the presets are for your specific YAML output options, but they can be changed. BTW, for lecture notes, I used to use `output: tint::tinthtml`. You have footnotes, margin notes, blockquotes... Anyway...

Comment: Thanks, @Kat. Maybe make that an answer, then I'll accept? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per your request, you can change the styles in HTML outputted R Markdown scripts by adding styles. There are a few different ways you can add them. Typically, I just place this content in between chunks.

```
<style>
blockquote {
  font-color: black; 
  opacity: 1;}
</style>
```

You can attach an external style document or use a CSS chunk. I just find this easier for most projects.

You can read more about this [here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/html-css.html).